# C# How to find out if array includes string twice

Tags: c#, arrays, string, include, equals

i want to check if a string array includes a string more than one time.

for example

```
string[] array = new string[]{"A1","A2","A3"};
string item = "A1";
```

look for item in array, include item just once return false

```
string[] array = new string[]{"A1","A2","A3","A1"};
string item = "A1";
```

return true

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `array.count(x=>x==item)==2`

Comment: Or `array.Distinct()` and comparing this length vs original will check for all entries

Comment: @Sayse That will return if any item is repeated, not for the particular item.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - The first sentence is slightly ambiguous which is why I built upon Mohammads comment

Comment: @Selman22 I strongly suspect is this a duplicate of the related thread? Find some other question please, or reopen it.

Comment: can you clarify your question ? do you want only check whether a specific item is repeated or not ? or do you want to make sure all items are unique ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know whether or not a particular item is repeated more than once, you can get the count of the item and check if it is bigger than `1`:

```
bool isRepeated = array.Count(x => x == item) > 1;
```

Or, you can do it more efficiently with a `HashSet`:

```
bool isRepeated = false;
var set = new HashSet<int>();
foreach(var x in array)
{
    if(x == item && !set.Add(x)) 
    {
       isRepeated = true; 
       break;
    }
}
```